# calculation of value from given matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

suppose that we have following array :

```
a=[12 21 23 10 34 54 10 9 5 6 7 8]

a =

    12    21    23    10    34    54    10     9     5     6     7     8
```

length(a)=

```
length(a)

ans =

    12
```

now i want  to create following  vector  b ,which b(1),b(2)...b(6) are following

```
b(1)=sqrt(a(1)^2+a(2)^2)
 b(2)=sqrt(a(3)^2+a(4)^2)

 b(3)=sqrt(a(5)^2+a(6)^2))
 b(4)=sqrt(a(7)^2+a(8)^2)
  b(5)=sqrt(a(9)^2+a(10)^2))
 b(6)=sqrt(a(11)^2+a(12)^2)
```

i have wrote  following code

```
or i=2:2:length(a)
   b(i/2)=sqrt(a(i-1)^2+a(i)^2);
end
>> b

b =

   24.1868   25.0799   63.8122   13.4536    7.8102   10.6301
```

but i am not sure if it is correct,pleas  help me to clarify if everything is ok in my code

Comment: *i am not sure if it is correct*   What tests have you made to assure yourself that your solution is correct ?  Which of those tests have produced results that cause you concern ?

Comment: from my array according the procedure i have mentioned

Comment: ok i  checked,it works fine

Comment: no  i prefer to stay,because next time if i need code,i would look ,anyone can post answer and i will accept   (will increase his and my reputation both)

Comment: This posting is off-topic because it does not ask a question about a programming problem.  It might belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matlab, loops are quite slow. Using vectors is much faster. I suggest therefore a solution without a loop:

```
a_1 = a(1:2:end);
a_2 = a(2:2:end);

b = sqrt(a_1.^2 + a_2.^2);
```

first, you create a vector `a_1` containing all elements with odd indices of `a` and a vector `a_2` containing all elements with even indices.
Then you square them element wise (`.^`) and take the square of the sum.
For you example of `a`, this is 75 times faster. As you increase the size of the array, you will save even more time.